# In a windows batch file how do I find out what credentials I am running under?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to detect that my batch file is running under a given domain's accounts (i.e. when my batch file is executed using `runas`).   How do I do that?

Comment: I forgot to add a critical piece of information:   I am using the /netonly  option of runas.
The given solutions do not tell me the /user in the command line
call runas /netonly /user:otherdomain\othertevya   xxx.cmd

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `whoami` command.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771299(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I think this would be a bit overkill for a batch file since you'd have to isolate the output of the command and process it (split the `domain\user` and compare both); the environment variables are a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%USERDOMAIN%` and `%USERNAME%` environment variables.